# How to import a docker container from its folder and/or config files?

Tags: docker, import

I've accidentally removed all my docker containers.

I had several containers running postgresql, sharelatex, nextcloud, etc. I tried to follow [THESE](https://www.linuxbabe.com/cloud-storage/integrate-collabora-online-server-nextcloud-ubuntu-16-04) instructions in order to integrate Collabora Online Server with Nextcloud. One of the instructions is to change the storage drive from AUFS to Device Mapper, and so I did.

After I restarted docker, all my containers have gone. I tried to undo the storage drive change by deleting the /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/DeviceMapper.conf file, with no success.

When I place the command "docker ps -a, it shows no containers. However, I can see the folders of the containers in the /var/lib/docker/containers folders.

How can I import them again without loosing data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use command 
Docker load -i 
Make sure you go to the directory where images are
See if it works for you,
I loaded my images using these commands

Comment: Thanks for the help but it did not work. This command is to import a container from a tarball.